# How can I preserve mushrooms for a long time?

Tags: food-preservation, mushrooms

Whenever I freeze mushrooms their color gets blackish, and their taste is altered. How can I preserve mushrooms for a long time while minimizing or eliminating this kind of changes?

Comment: Mushrooms will store fine in the freezer if they are cooked first. You can blanch them in boiling water. Or you can sauté them in butter or oil and then freeze the mixture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot preserve them without a change in taste and color. Freezing is the best you will get, and the changes you desecribe are normal. You can also dehydrate or pressure can them, but they will be even more different than fresh mushrooms then.

Comment: You means that i cannot use the freezing mushrooms without changing its taste and also its color.

Comment: Exactly. And other preservation methods change them even more.